# Finding the co-ordinates of image pixels within a specified range in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, logical-operators

I have a grayscale image loaded as a numpy array in python. I would like to find the co-ordinates where the image intensities are within a specified range, say `[lowerlim,upperlim]`. I tried finding using `numpy.where`as

```
np.where(image>lowerlim and image<upperlim)
```

But it is giving error - 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.' Can anyone guide me how to do this in python?

Comment: You are probably looking for [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) instead of the regular `and`

Comment: Thanks @cel ... that solved the problem. The command I used: np.where(np.logical_and(image>lowerlim,image<upperlim))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As says in comment you need to use [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) if you want to use a logical and for numpy arrays , and for pick the specified elements you can pass the `np.where` to your array :

```
>>> a
array([[[ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [20, 39]]])
>>> np.where(np.logical_and(3<a,a<10))
(array([0, 0, 1]), array([1, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 0]))
>>> a[np.where(np.logical_and(3<a,a<10))]
array([4, 5, 9])
```

Or instead of `np.where` you can directly use [`np.extract`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.extract.html) :

```
>>> np.extract(np.logical_and(3<a,a<10),a)
array([4, 5, 9])
```

Comment: On a side note, the `&` operator will work just fine in place of `np.logical_and`.  E.g. `(a > 3) & (a < 10)` instead of `np.logical_and(a>3,a<10)`.